# Generate custom setter lombok or intelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, jackson, lombok

I have a Dto class like this :

```
@Setter @Getter
public class UserDTO {

    private String firstName;

    private String lastName;

}
```

and i read somewhere when no field send to jackson , we can get change like this :

```
public boolean isModifiedFirstName = false;

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.isModifiedFirstName = true;
    this.firstName = firstName;
}
```

How to generate like this code with lombok ?
or even intelliJ template not generate isModified boolean field

for my problem how to get json field are sent to jackson like this :

```
{
"firstName":null,
"lastname":"someName"
}
```

diffrent with :

```
{
"lastName" : "someName"
}
```

im searching how to get jackson null vs not defined field and found can get diffrent in setter method.

now i need custom setter for my DTOs to get null vs undifined json fields.
thanks

Comment: Hi Mohsen, welcome to SO. In order to get an answer for your question, can you please explain your problem in more detail? It's not really clear how Jackson is involved all of this. Thanks

Comment: @PimHazebroek hey thank for reply im update questoin

Answer (score 0):

Lombok does not have an option to generate 'isChanged'-style fields. You'd have to write it out long-form.

I don't see why you need it here; if the JSON input has a `null` value, then, it would just end up on the java side as `null` too and that's how you know.

Comment: because i need my json is null or not send to me

Answer (score 0):

You could initialize the properties to something other than `null`:

```
@Setter @Getter
public class UserDTO {

    private String firstName = "empty";

    private String lastName = "empty";

}
```

You can pick a value that is unlikely to be received as input. then you will know if the property was set during deserialization.